# Connecting a widget to a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipywidgets

I'm trying to use ipywidget play to create an animation that changes with the slider. However, it is only passing the initial value and not updating, how do I fix this?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
from matplotlib import animation
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
%matplotlib notebook
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import HBox, VBox, interact, interactive, fixed, 
interact_manual
from IPython.display import display

play = widgets.Play(
   interval=10,
   value= 0,
   min=0,
   max=100,
   step=1,
   description="Press play",
   disabled=False
)

slider = widgets.IntSlider()
widgets.jslink((play, 'value'), (slider, 'value'))
widgets.HBox([play, slider])

display(play, slider)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)     
y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
ax.plot(x, y, x*y * slider.value, lw = '2')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Where is the function that gets called by the slider?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When a slider is moved, it needs to call a function which will perform the action that you want to happen upon such slider event. However there is no such function in your code.

Comment: What would the function look like?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by ImportanceOfBeingErnest you need a function to work with ["interact"](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) in order to make the widgets interact with the plot

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
from matplotlib import animation
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'

import ipywidgets as widgets
interact_manual
from IPython.display import display

play = widgets.Play(
   interval=10,
   value= 0,
   min=0,
   max=100,
   step=1,
   description="Press play",
   disabled=False
)

slider = widgets.IntSlider()
widgets.jslink((play, 'value'), (slider, 'value'))
ui = widgets.HBox([play])

def f(slider):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
    x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
    y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
    ax.plot(x, y, x*y * slider, lw = '2')
    plt.show()
    return

display(ui)

interact(f,slider=slider)
```